# How to inject an instance instead of creating a dependency in a constructor?

Tags: android, dependency-injection

How to inject an instance in a constructor instead of creating a dependency? So my code right now looks like so:

```
public ClassA(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
    activity = (AppCompatActivity) presenter.getActivity(); 
    classB = new ClassB();
}
```

So my problem is with the **classB** instance. How can I inject it instead of creating an instance?

Comment: Why not able to inject via constructor like the presenter?

Comment: Have a look my answer